# Flutter CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am setting Firebase for my Flutter project. When I use `signInAnonymously()` method it throws this error:

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 9532): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@41ffdb0
I/flutter ( 9532): PlatformException(FirebaseException, An internal
error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.
], null) I/flutter ( 9532): error sign in
```

Comment: why did you use that title if this is the problem? I am facing the error in the title.

Comment: cause they're appear at same time

Comment: The question title is misleading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the API key for accessing firebase features is invalid.

Try this
Redownload the **`google-services.json`** file and place it in **android>app** directory 
Then run `flutter clean` then run the app again

Comment: I'm facing the same error but firebase works fine in 20 api level devices or higher, even having multidex enabled. Crashing when trying to use lower api levels, like 19.

Comment: @JoséPulido which version of firebase dependencies are you using?